# DATE() function in PowerBI not working - does not recognize year value

Tags: date, powerbi

Does anyone know why I am encountering this error with the most basic operation in PowerBI? After a few tries myself only ending in errors I copied the syntax straight off MS site and still......error.

I created a new table and used the following:

```
Table = calendar(date(2000,1,1),date(2030,12,31))
```

**Error received:**

> Too few arguments were passed to the DATE function. The minimum
>   argument count for the function is 3.

When adding the arguments its as if the DATE function does not recognize the year value at all.

Anyone else encountering this? 
Also, I noticed a lot of search results advising to use the "Modelling" tab which I don't have in my desktop version. I am currently still on a free trial.
Does a free trial mean I can not use the most basic DATE() function - I truly hope this is not the case.

[image]

Comment: What version of Power BI Desktop are you using? There is NO restriction in features in Power BI Desktop for Free/Pro users, only in the Web Service. The above code works for me when creating a new dax table

Comment: Yup, works perfectly fine. The problem is not in the part you exposed to us! How about  [Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's a reason why this is highly recommended.

Comment: Jonee I looked at the About section in my PBI and it says version 2.79.5768.1082 64-bit (March 2020).

Comment: Thanks for testing Peter - I have no other parts as this is the start of creating a calendar table in PBI. Besides clicking the "New table" option, I haven't done anything else. Hence I have no idea why this wouldn't work. If I use CALENDAR(1) it gives me the first column with a bunch of dates starting in 1899 (as expected) . So I know the CALENDARAUTO() function works.

Comment: The modelling tab will appear when on the Report section, you are on the table tab. It is the icon above it.